# How to parse string into function property in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, deserialization

I created custom stringify method to stringify function as follow

```
var myStringify=function (obj) {
      return JSON.stringify(obj, function (key, value) {
        if (value instanceof Function || typeof value == 'function') {
          return value.toString();
        }
        return value;
      });
    }
```

But when I have no idea about parsing string function into function object.
Here is my example

```
var parsed=JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

After processing JSON.parse function, I got following

parsed.run field has string of function

```
console.log(parsed.run)  // output is "function(){console.log('foo');}"
```

I want this function string back into property of parsed object,

```
{run:"function(){console.log('foo');}"}
```

into

```
{run:function(){console.log('foo');}}
```

how should I do?

Comment: `"function(){console.log('foo');}"` is not a valid JSON..

Comment: @RayonDabre, I know your point. I posted for short note: complete is 
parsed={run:"function(){console.log('foo');}"}. Thanks

Comment: Tell me why would this situation arise ? What you want to achieve ?

Comment: Have you tried `eval()`?

Comment: I want to pass some object to webworker and want to run object function inside webworker. if I can convert function string back to function I can run object function from webworker.

Comment: @PierreDuc, I've already tried eval() but it's for implementation only and not working, Thanks.

Comment: @RayonDabre It looks like he is trying to store javascript functions in a database.  Is that correct @KyawLay?

Comment: @dane, I assume the same...

Comment: @dane No I don't want to store function in database it's none sense. I just want to run object's function from webworker thread

Comment: @dane sorry, far away from my logic, you know that object cannot be passed directly to worker? I need to convert into JSON string so that it can be send through postmessage() method. I know this is insane but what I want to do to parse original object from json on worker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a regex to match function-strings:

```
var parseFunctionString = /^\s*function(\s+[a-z0-9$_]*)?\(([^)]*)\)\s*\{([\s\S]*)\}\s*$/i;
//extended regExp, to handle fat-arrow-notation
//var parseFunctionString = /^\s*(?:function(\s+[a-z0-9$_]*)?\(([^)]*)\)\s*\{([\s\S]*)\}|\(([^)]*)\)\s*=>([\s\S]*)|([a-z0-9$_]+)\s*=>([\s\S]*))\s*$/i;
```

and the usage:

```
JSON.parse(input, function(k,v){
    var m = typeof v === "string" && v.match(parseFunctionString);
    if(m){
        return Function(m[2], m[3]);
        //if you include the extended regExp
        //return Function(m[2] || m[4] || m[6], m[3] || "return "+( m[5] || m[7] ));

        //return Function("return " + m[0])();
    }
    return v;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the body first

```
var string = parsed.run;
var body = string.substring(string.indexOf("{") + 1, string .lastIndexOf("}"));
```

Now create a new function object and execute

```
new Function(body)();
```

You can try a simple **demo** on your browser console as

```
var string = "function(){console.log('foo');}";
var body = string.substring(string.indexOf("{") + 1, string .lastIndexOf("}"));
new Function(body)(); //outputs foo
```

Refactor this into a function

```
function convertBodyToFunction(body)
{
   body = string.substring(string.indexOf("{") + 1, string .lastIndexOf("}"));
   return new Function(body);
}
convertBodyToFunction(parsed.run)();
```